# How do I have a link from a Google Chrome extension popup open in the same tab underneath?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want the link to appear in the tab beneath resulting in the popup going away.

Currently have this:

```
//Open links in tab from popup
if (document.location.search == '?popup')
$('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

But the _blanks opens in a new tab. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to get the current selected tab first via,
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getSelected

Then you use the tab.id, that the callback has fired, and updating it with a url:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update

For example:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected({}, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'http://google.com'});
});
```

If you want to let every link in the popup page to update the current tab opened. You can do the following (as you mentioned within the comments but with currentTarget):

```
$('a').live('click', function(e) {
  var href = e.currentTarget.href;
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: href});
  });
  window.close(); // To close the popup.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Instead of a specific URL like you provided, how do I do it for all links on the popup like I had in the example?

Comment: Something like this isn't working for me:                  //Opens all links from popup in same tab underneath
  if (document.location.search == '?popup')
 $('a').live('click', function(e) {
  var href = e.targetElement.href;
  chrome.tabs.getSelected({}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: href});
  });
 });

Comment: Are there any errors in the Inspector, when you right click on the popup and choose inspect?

Comment: There is not. Although I cannot right click on the popup, I have to see it in the full screen version.

Comment: We will take this privately, and once we have a conclusion, we will share it back to StackedOverflow :)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I just sent you an email!

Comment: No problem! I updated the answer above in case other people will find it useful.