# Chrome Extension: How do i open urls in popup.html in the same tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, url, manifest

Google Chrome extension:

i am running mad on a simple thing. Please dont blame me, i am not english origin and i have trouble to read and understand all the extension docs.

I simply want to do the following:

I have lets say 8 different URLs in my popop.html which opens when i click on my icon in the top right browserbar.
(url) example.com
(url) Other Example and etc ...

clicking an url does nothing, `target="_blank"` opens always a new tab but i want to open them all in the same tab when clicking on one. `target="_top"` or `target="_self"` doesnt seem work here.

I have no idea how to program this. I come rather from php and i need a quick solution.

Has anyone a litte ready (easy to understand) code snippet or an Idea how to open my urls in the same tab ? (where to place what) 
( i understood the manifest definitions so far, but all this java up and down is too difficult to understand for me at the moment only for this "simple" task).

Thanks in Advance
RJ

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765004/how-do-i-have-a-link-from-a-google-chrome-extension-popup-open-in-the-same-tab-u

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate to that question, the correct answer is more direct and better

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that chrome does not allow the popups to open an external page by any way. The only solution I know is to place an `iframe` in your `popup.html` file with `src` attribute set to  `popup2.html` and place all your html inside `popup2.html`. However, consider that all websites do not work well inside iframe.

**If you are trying to open url in currently active tab then try following:**

Attach following script to your popup.html file:

```
var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

function openLink() {
    var href = this.href;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: href});
    });
}

for (var i=0,a; a=hrefs[i]; ++i) {
    hrefs[i].addEventListener('click', openLink);
}
```

You need to add `tabs` permisson to your manifest file for this to work.

Comment: I tried this. Links without target="XY" open now inside the popop window itself, thats a good trick if you want this to happen. Though I still cant open the urls in the browsers main window in the same tab when clicking on them. :-(

Comment: I needed to place your code in a separate .js Chrome doesnt ecept code in the popup.html. I have Tabs permission in my manifest. But your code didnt help. do i need to replace something in that code with "popup.html" or so ? I tested the .js and your function with a little document.write("hellO") it seems the js. is linked properly but the function is never called...

Comment: make sure to place your script tag before the closing body tag

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use `chrome.tabs.update({active: true, url: 'yoursite.com'});` instead of `chrome.windows.create({url:'yoursite.com'});` and the location will be opened in the same active tab

Comment: I'm working with omnibox api, this code helped me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I'll post the working code, as of 2018.

To open anchor links from Chrome extension in the same window, place this code in your popup.js:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        (function () {
            var ln = links[i];
            var location = ln.href;
            ln.onclick = function () {
                chrome.tabs.update({active: true, url: location});
            };
        })();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

This may be a simple fix if I understand you correctly;

For each of the links that you want to open in the same tab, use this HTML:

```
<a href="LINK" target="_self">Link Name</a>
```

A simpler way of writing this is to do:

```
<a href="LINK">Link Name</a>
```

Hope I was of help :)

Comment: Thanks, no this only works in a normal html site . My question concerns the google chrome extensions. My popup.html opens in a popup when i click on the my icon in the chrome browser. A normal Link does nothing, adding _top or _self doesnt work here, when i add target="blank" it opens in a new tab but i want to open them all in the same tab (or window).