# Chrome extension : open a link from popup.html that replaces the popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I apologize if the question has already been answered somewhere in this website, but I'm having troubles with something that seems so easy to do.

I have a popup.html that displays a little menu with 3 elements inside. One Among them is "Enable".
All I want it to do when I click on it is that it replaces the current popup.html with another popup that displays something else.

I've heard about `window.location.href=` but I can't make it work

Here's my manifest.json

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "e-kootsa",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Ce plugin vous permet d'écouter le texte d'une page",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Here is my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
.selection{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.global{
    padding-top: 5px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="global">
    <div class="selection"><a href="options.html" target="_blank">Paramètres</a></div>
    <hr />
    <div class="selection" id="clickme"><a href="#">Activer</a></div>
    <hr />
    <div class="selection"><a href="about.html" target="_blank">À propos</a>        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My "test" popup to show just contains "Test" in it and is called popup2.html

Any idea ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245577/chrome-extension-how-do-i-open-urls-in-popup-html-in-the-same-tab

Comment: Thank you ! I'll check the link right away