# Opening a custom page upon click on google chrome extension icon

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to open a new custom page like "p.html" (that I load with the maps_app to the browser) when I click the google extension icon. It shouldn't be a new tab as other questions answer, but replace the current tab. To open in the present tab, to say the least.

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765004/how-do-i-have-a-link-from-a-google-chrome-extension-popup-open-in-the-same-tab-u

Comment: não tinha visto não sr filipe, obrigadinho porreiraço!